# Trying to draw a line on a JPanel but only draws a dot

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, draw

I'm trying to make a program that will be able to draw lines on a white background on a JPanel. I have other classes to make selections for colors and width sizes, but for now I'm just trying to figure out how to draw lines. This is my "DrawingPanel" class which contains the code for the JPanel I will be drawing on. Right now what happens is if I click down my mouse and drag it across the screen a dot follows the mouse, but I want a line to be drawn by the mouse. Please help.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel
{
    private Graphics g;
    private int x, y, startx, starty;
    public DrawingPanel ()
    {
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionSensor ());
    }

    public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
    {
        //super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        System.out.println(x + " " + y);
        g.drawLine(startx,starty,x,y);
    }

    public class MouseMotionSensor implements MouseMotionListener, MouseListener
    {
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) 
        {
            x = e.getX();
            y = e.getY();
            repaint();
            startx = x;
            starty = y;
        }
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
        {
            startx = e.getX();
            starty = e.getY();
        }
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}

    }
}
```

Comment: In addition to Joel's answer, you also need to addMouseListener with the same parameters (not just mouseMotionListener), because your startx/y is not registered otherwise.

Comment: `repaint()` is asynchronous, so the actual painting happens later. `startx = x; starty = y;` means that **start and end points are the same**, by the time painting happens, and a line that starts and ends at the same point will look like a dot.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem may be that in mouseDragged you're changing both startx and starty, and x and y while the mouse is being dragged. While the mouse is being dragged, you want the start location (startx and starty) to be the same, and you want the end location (x and y) to change, so remove the those two lines in mouseDragged, so as to only change x and y.

Comment: @RIVERMAN2010 That's exactly what this answer is already saying: "only changing x and y" => "don't change startx and starty" => "delete the code doing it".

Comment: The answer is correct, as for how to fix the code, but lack explanation of why (see duplicates for why).

Comment: Sorry, I think my question wasn't clear. I'm not just trying to draw straight lines. I also want to draw curved lines and I want to be able to draw multiple lines. When I test my code with the changes made, there are two issues. First, it can only draw straight lines when I want to be able to draw curves. Second, it can only draw one line at a time but I want to be able to have multiple lines on the screen.